# Facing 'Field expression not allowed for generic SObject' in my class

Tags: sobject

```
//ICRE
Map<String,String> objName = new Map<String,String>();
for(Schema.SObjectType f : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
    if(f.getDescribe().isCustom()){
        objName.put(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getName());
    }
}                                    

if(objName.containsKey('ICRE')){
    Map<Id,sObject> mapClonedICRE = new Map<Id,sObject>();
    string sObj = objName.get('ICRE');
    system.debug('sObj::'+sObj);
    sObject oInstance;                                    
    sDynamicQuery = this.dynamicQuery(sObj);
    query = 'SELECT ' + sDynamicQuery + ' FROM '+ sObj +' WHERE Product__c IN :lstProdOfSourceEE limit 5000';
    lstofICRE = Database.query(query);
    system.debug('lstofICRE::'+lstofICRE);

    for(sObject oICRE :lstofICRE){        
        oInstance = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObj).newSObject();                                         
        oInstance = oICRE.clone(false, false, false, false); 
        system.debug('oInstanceNew::'+oInstance);  
        //oInstance.oInstance.get('ownerId') = userinfo.getuserid();
        /*oInstance.ownerId = userinfo.getuserid();                                                                                                                           
          if(mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.containskey(oICRE.Product__c)){
            oInstance.Product__c = mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id;
          }else{
            oInstance.Product__c = null;
          }

          if(oICRE.Start_Date__c != null)
            oInstance.Start_Date__c = String.valueOf(oTargetEE.get('Start_Date__c'));                                            

          if(oICRE.End_Date__c != null)
            oInstance.End_Date__c = oTargetEE.End_Date__c;

          if(oInstance.Product__c != null){
            mapClonedICRE.put(oICRE.Id, oInstance);
          }*/                                       
    }
    if(!mapClonedICRE.isEmpty()){
        Insert mapClonedICRE.values();
        system.debug('ICRE::'+mapClonedICRE.values().size());
        system.debug('ICRECon::'+mapClonedICRE.values());
    }
}
```

Error on this Line -

> oInstance.Product__c = mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id;

Comment: Can you please tell what is the map key and value type?

Comment: Map Key - Product Id and Value - product object instance(Map<Id, Product2> mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId = new Map<Id, Product2>();)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty descriptive of your issue.

A 'field expression' is something like `myObjectInstance.myField`, using dot notation on an object instance to get or set the value of a field.

As the error states, you aren't allowed to do this on generic `SObject` instances.

Taking a look at some very specific parts of your provided code, we see this

```
for(sObject oICRE :lstofICRE){
    // other code

    oInstance.Product__c = mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id;

    // more code
}
```

`oICRE` and `oInstance` are generic `sObjects` in this loop, so `oInstance.Product__c` and `oICRE.Product__c` are the specific parts of the line giving you your error.

To work around that, you need to use the `SObject.get(_field_)` method (when you need to fetch a value from an SObject) and the `SObject.put(_field_, _value_)` (when you need to set a value on an SObject)
 methods instead

```
for(sObject oICRE :lstofICRE){
    // other code

    // Instead of using dot notation, you'll need to use the get() and put() methods
    //   and pass a string matching the API name of your target field
    oInstance.put('Product__c',  mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.get('Product__c')).Id);

    // more code
}
```

There are a few other instances in your provided class where you attempt to directly reference a field on a generic `SObject` (like `if(oICRE.Start_Date__c != null)`). You'll need to do the same thing (use `get()` and/or `put()`) to those as well.

Answer (score -1):

Please use

```
//ICRE
Map<String,String> objName = new Map<String,String>();
for(Schema.SObjectType f : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
    if(f.getDescribe().isCustom()){
        objName.put(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getName());
    }
}                                    

if(objName.containsKey('ICRE')){
    Map<Id,sObject> mapClonedICRE = new Map<Id,sObject>();
    string sObj = objName.get('ICRE');
    system.debug('sObj::'+sObj);
    sObject oInstance;                                    
    sDynamicQuery = this.dynamicQuery(sObj);
    query = 'SELECT ' + sDynamicQuery + ' FROM '+ sObj +' WHERE Product__c IN :lstProdOfSourceEE limit 5000';
    lstofICRE = Database.query(query);
    system.debug('lstofICRE::'+lstofICRE);

    for(sObject oICRE :lstofICRE){        
        oInstance = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObj).newSObject();                                         
        oInstance = oICRE.clone(false, false, false, false); 
        system.debug('oInstanceNew::'+oInstance);  
        //oInstance.oInstance.get('ownerId') = userinfo.getuserid();
        /*oInstance.ownerId = userinfo.getuserid();                                                                                                                           
          if(mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.containskey(oICRE.Product__c)){
            oInstance.put('Product__c', mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id);
            //oInstance.Product__c = mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id;
          }else{
            oInstance.put('Product__c', null);
            //oInstance.Product__c = null;
          }

          if(oICRE.Start_Date__c != null)
            oInstance.put('Start_Date__c', String.valueOf(oTargetEE.get('Start_Date__c'));
            //oInstance.Start_Date__c = String.valueOf(oTargetEE.get('Start_Date__c'));                                            

          if(oICRE.End_Date__c != null)
            oInstance.put('End_Date__c', oTargetEE.End_Date__c);
            //oInstance.End_Date__c = oTargetEE.End_Date__c;

          if(oInstance.get('Product__c') != null){
            mapClonedICRE.put(oICRE.Id, oInstance);
          }*/                                       
    }
    if(!mapClonedICRE.isEmpty()){
        Insert mapClonedICRE.values();
        system.debug('ICRE::'+mapClonedICRE.values().size());
        system.debug('ICRECon::'+mapClonedICRE.values());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be:   oInstance.put('Product__c', mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id);

Comment: I got the error,Method does not exist(sobject).put[string]

Comment: yes you are right its my bad it will be oInstance.put('Product__c', mapClonedPrdwithSourcePrdId.get(oICRE.Product__c).Id);

Comment: I changed the the line but still facing the fields expression error.

Comment: Hi made changes for sobject expression in whole of the code please check my above edited code

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but is incomplete. It is also simply a 'code dump' (a block of code with little to no explanation), which typically aren't useful answers. Explanation is vital to the OP (original poster) being able to recognize what was wrong with their original code _and how to avoid similar problems in the future_. Explanation also helps different people that may come to this question in the future apply this answer to their similar _but different_ circumstances.